# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): can't access property "country", this.props is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i'm working on a react app

when run this function by infinite scroll i'll get error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): can't access property "country",
> this.props is undefined

```
async pageUpdater() {
  let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=myapi&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
  this.setState({ loading: true })
  await fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    this.setState({ articles: data.articles, totalResults: data.totalResults, loading: false })
  })
}
```

Comment: Presumably then `this.props` is `undefined`.  And you can't read a property of `undefined` because it has no properties.  How is this function used in your component?  What should `this.props` be in this case and why?  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i am using this function inside componentDidMount and it works and render news
`async componentDidMount() {
        this.pageUpdater()
    }`
but when we scroll page down using infinite scroll  component fetch more data to render it show error

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the arrow function or need to bind the `this` with this function.

The JavaScript has the function scope and the `this` pointer is changed on the function scope.

For example-

```js
const pageUpdater = async () => {
 // your code here
}
```

or

You also could bind the this with the function at the component connstructor.

```js
constructor() {
  this.pageUpdater = this.pageUpdater.bind(this);
}
```

For more about `this` read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this